# Fitting a curve knowing points uncertainty

Tags: curve-fitting, uncertainty, interpolation

I have a set of points X and Y that represent a curve. It is not a linear curve but a model I cannot estimate analitically. I know the uncertainy on Y (1 sigma) and there is no uncertainty on X. Due to these uncertainties, the points are not always elegantly aligned as you can see in the image below.[image].

**My question is the following**:
Does exist a method that, taking into account the uncertainties on the Y coordinate, will allow me to modify the curve in order to have a better estimated model, with correctly aligned points. In this case, is there a library, for example in R, that I could use? This method could allow me to add points as well in some locations (interpolate some missing points, for example around X = 0.1). For the interpolation, I know that I could perform linear or log interpolation, but I really want to consider the Y uncertainties. I would like, as a result, a set of new points (X,Y).

The objective is to smooth the curve without damaging the accuracy. The uncertainty on each point is 0.9% and I would like to construct a smoothed curves based on this one, keeping an uncertainty close to 1%. For instance it could be done by generating many curves by samling the points in their uncertainty, and then computing the mean of all curves. This would probably give me a smoothed curve without any points having such discrepancies as the ones represented in red.
Many thanks for your help/suggestions.

Comment: Your question is extremely broad because, as a general proposition, you are asking about procedures generally known as "statistical modeling," "curve fitting," or "regression."  If you could supply additional information about what you mean by "better" and what is an allowable "modification" of your curve, then we could provide relevant advice.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer whuber. In fact, I am opened to propositions. I have knowledge of curve fitting, but no knowledge of fitting, taking into account information carried in the uncertainty. I am looking for smoothing the curve. For instance, one possibility would be to create a high number of curves, considering the statistical uncertainty associated to the Y points by MonteCarlo processes and then considering the mean of all resulting curves. But I am wondering if exist more sophisticated methods already programmed in some libraries. I want the resulting curve is not with higher errors

Comment: Please do not close my question. I have added some information to clarify the points you mentionned.

Comment: Nonparametric regression, splines, Fourier basis, additive models, neural networks...those terms should get you started, though the last and even second-to-last might require quite a bit more data than you have. (All of them might require more data than you have in order to get a good feel for the true phenomenon, but you’re particularly pushing your luck with the last two, especially neural nets.)